# Every time getting error of exists validator of Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Following is my code of validating campaign_id from database
but every time I am getting error weather this record is in db or not

```
[campaign_id', 'exist', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\Campaign', 'filter' => ['campaign_id' => Campaign::className()], 'message' => 'There is no record with this id.' ]]
```

Comment: this id is unique in db

Answer (score 0):

i got solution, just removed this filter and it gets work

```
['campaign_id', 'exist',
            'targetClass' => '\common\models\Campaign',
            'message' => 'There is no user with this email address.'
        ]
```